# How to troubleshoot Slim REST API by simulating HTTP

Tags: php, ide, slim

I am new to http://www.slimframework.com/, but it is easy and I have the basics working.  Now I wish to go through some of my script which is initiated by slimframework using an IDE (PhpED).

I suppose I could just set the URL as needed for a GET request, and make a HTML form and submit it for POST requests.

I expect there has to be a better way.  How can I specify the method, url, and body so that I can troubleshoot the script?

Comment: Use `curl` inside your unit tests?

Comment: @arkascha.  Guess I need to read up on "unit tests".  I've been meaning to, but haven't gotten around to it, and have never used them.

Comment: You definitely want to use them from your projects start on. Do not postpone that. Only makes things worse in the end.

Comment: @arkascha  Off topic, but do you have any recommendations on a good getting started tutorial on the subject?  Thanks

Comment: The project comes with documentation and a short "getting started" section: https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Comment: Try https://www.getpostman.com

Comment: you can use Guzzle to simulate requests to your API... but honestly you should be mocking the Request/Response in your Unit tests. Take a look at the slim source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into a handy tool called [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Once downloaded and open, you can specify URL, body, method and much more, send the request and look at the response. Parsed or unparsed. It lets you add collections so you can actually rebuild your entire API calls.